# Some confusion in creating pivot table

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a pivot table but i am not getting the result i want. Couldn't able to understand why is this happening.

I have a dataframe like this -

```
    data_channel_is_lifestyle   data_channel_is_bus     shares
0       0.0                               0.0            593
1       0.0                               1.0            711
2       0.0                               1.0            1500
3       0.0                               0.0            1200
4       0.0                               0.0            505
```

And the result i am looking for is name of the columns in the index and sum of shares in the column. So
i did this -

```
news_copy.pivot_table(index=['data_channel_is_lifestyle','data_channel_is_bus'], values='shares', aggfunc=sum)
```

but i am getting the result something like this -

```
                                                   shares
data_channel_is_lifestyle   data_channel_is_bus     
            0.0                    0.0             107709305
            1.0                                    19168370            
            1.0                    0.0              7728777
```

I don't want these 0's and 1's, i just want the result to be something like this -

```
                               shares
data_channel_is_lifestyle     107709305 
data_channel_is_bus           19168370
```

How can i do this?

Comment: So you want to sum `shares` where `data_channel_is_lifestyle==1` and similar for `data_channel_is_bus`?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, that is what i am looking for. Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you put it, it's just matrix multipliation:

```
df.filter(like='data').T@(df[['shares']])
```

Output (for sample data):

```
                           shares
data_channel_is_lifestyle     0.0
data_channel_is_bus        2211.0
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't able to understand your answer. what will go in the like='data' and what is @ after T. Is it from new version of pandas?

Comment: @bholaprasad since your `data_channel_is_lifestyle` looks binary (`0` or `1`), summing over `1` values just means that you sum the product of `data_channel_is_lifestyle` and `shares`. And that's exactly [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition).

Comment: @bholaprasad `df.filter(like='data')` returns a dataframe with columns which contains `data` as a string in it , then using a transpose and a [dot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) multiplication it returns the above result.